# Sliding Tabbar Highlight React Native

Tags: react-native, tabbar

Attempting to replicate the following but for a bottom tabbar (moving an underlying blue line that follows the user selection underneath the tabbar):

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brentvatne/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/master/demo.gif

Here is what I have so far (but the red underline doesn't slide and is static based on the user's selection):

[image]

So far here is my code:

```
return <Tabbar 
                    selected={this.state.selected} 
                    tabHeight={window.height/16}
                    style={styles.menu}
                    onTabItemPress={name => this.setState({ selected: name })}
                    renderTabComponent
                    renderTabComponent={(name, isActive) => (
                    <View
                        style={[
                          { borderBottomWidth: 2, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' },
                          isActive ? { borderColor: '#DB202A'} : { borderColor: 'transparent' }
                        ]}>
                      <Text style={styles.menuText}>{ name }</Text>
                    </View>
                    )}>
                        <Tabbar.Item name="Causes" >
                            <Text>This is the Causes tab</Text>
                        </Tabbar.Item>
                        <Tabbar.Item name="Trending" >
                            <Text>This is the Trending tab</Text>
                        </Tabbar.Item>
                        <Tabbar.Item 
                            name="Home" >
                            <View style={styles.containerSuper}>
                                <View style={styles.container}>
                                    {this.renderListView()}
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </Tabbar.Item>
                        <Tabbar.Item name="Profile" >
                            <Text>This is the Profile tab</Text>
                        </Tabbar.Item>
                        <Tabbar.Item name="Settings" >
                            <Text>This is the Settings tab</Text>
                        </Tabbar.Item>
                </Tabbar>
```

Comment: Please explain further what difficulty you are having. The module you're basing your work off of is open-source, and you can easily view its code here: https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-scrollable-tab-view

Comment: @JohnShammas just added more information - i suppose I could delve deeper in the back end code but the work around in doing so is quite difficult as a novice to such customization - I've given it a try but don't seem to get it working well